# How do I use hg push in Mercurial

Tags: windows, mercurial, commit, hgweb

I've spent some time converting my SVN repository to Mercurial. I've setup Mercurial under IIS7 on Win 2008 R2.

I have nearly everything working. However I can not push changes back to server.

```
$ hg push
http authorization required
realm: pandora
user: rich
password: 
pushing to https://pandora/dev/test
searching for changes
abort: HTTP Error 500: .hg\store\00changelog.i: Access is denied
```

My hgweb.cgi looks like this:

```
[web]
baseurl = /hg
allow_push = *

[trusted]
users = *
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Looks like it may be an IIS permissions error.

Comment: Any idea what kind of permission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok turns out this is a permission problem.

You need to ensure the location of the repository has gives the SERVER/User write permission. Once changed everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing to:

```
https://<username>:<password>@pandora/dev/test
```

Comment: that gives me 'abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found'